# Why logarithm of a negative number to a negative base is not defined?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I have studied that the numbers of the form N=aˣ can be written as $\log_aN=x \;\forall N>0, a>0, a\not=1.$

Let's take $N=-8$ and $a=-2$ then $-8=(-2)^3$ and $\log_{(-2)}-8 = 3$.

Why there are restrictions on the number and the base even though $\log_{(-2)}-8 = 3$ is defined? Is there something I'm missing as I'm only learning the propaedeutics of mathematics?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It does make sense to assert that $\log_{(-2)} [-8] = 3$, but what about $\log_{(-2)} [-4]$ or, for that matter $\log_{(-2)} [-8.01]$?  The point of logarithms is to solve problems.  What problem solving is facilitated by defining base $(-2)$ logarithms for isolated numbers, such as $-2, -8,$ or $-32$?

Comment: @user2661923 Logarithms exist regardless of whether they're of any use to us.

Comment: Full understanding of problem you will get, if you read about complex logarithms.

Comment: Questions about logs with negative bases have been asked and answered here many times already. Please see the list under Related for some of them, doubtless there are many others you can find by doing a search.

Comment: And what the heck are propaedeutics?

Comment: If you're now unable to see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4364613), and you still want to read it, let me know by pinging me here.

Answer (score 2):

If $a>0$, then $a^x$ is defined for every real number $x$ and, if $y>0$, what we denote by $\log_ay$ is the only $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $a^x=y$.

But if $a<0$ then $a^x$ is defined only for some numbers $x$; for instance, $a^{1/2}$ is undefined. That's why we don't talk about $\log_ay$; it's undefined for most numbers $y$.

Comment: @user21820 It's gone.

Comment: Thanks a lot! =)

Answer (score 0):

In the special case when the given number and base both are *real negative*, log is well defined in terms of complex numbers and there are no restrictions.

$$ \log _{-a}(-N)=\frac{\log (-N)}{\log (-a)}= \frac{\log (N) + i \pi}{\log (a)+ i \pi} $$

$$=\frac{\pi-i\log (N)}{\pi-i\log (a)}$$

which is a complex number. The new unlabeled base can be again ***any real*** number ***b***.

EDIT1:

If new base $b$ is positive then there is no problem but if negative we again have

$$ b= - |b|,\quad \log _{\;b} N =\frac {\log N }{\log b}=\frac {\log N }{i \pi+ \log |b|} $$

and the nestings / branch cuts of log can  propogate continuously depending on the sign of newly chosen/introduced bases.

Comment: I think you will find that the final expression you have written down is NOT independent of the choice of (positive, real) base. They also depend on the choice of branch of logarithm you chose when you wrote $\log(-a)=\log(a)+i\pi$.

Comment: Thanks, edited to include choice of sign of new base, hope OK.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear. Pick some positive numbers $a$ and $N$. Pick two different positive bases, $b$ and $b'$. Calculate $(\pi-i\log_bN)/(\pi-i\log_ba)$ and $(\pi-i\log_{b'}N)/(\pi-i\log_{b'}a)$. Are they the same?

Comment: And there's still the matter of choosing a branch for $\log_b(-N)$.

Comment: In short, this answer is wrong, Narasimham. Why is it still here?